# INSERT INTO returns operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data from a excel sheet to database. All rows in a single query.

I searched and found that to insert multiple rows in a single query i have to make query like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name(c1,c2) VALUES( (value1,value2),(value1,value2))
```

This is how my `INSERT INTO` query looks like for `single row`

```
INSERT INTO December_2015(S_No,Zone,State,City2,VM_Town,Distibutor_Code,Distributor_Name,Dealer_Code,Dealer_Name,Category,Address,Location,Contact,Mobile_No,Visit_1,Visit_2,Visit_3,Visit_4,Visit_5,Visit_6) VALUES(('1','South','Telanagana','Hyderabad','Y','1006704','Sai Santhoshi Enterprises','TG000999','Sree Laxmi Mobiles','A','F4,anthem Arcade,gujarathi Galli,koti ','Koti','Rajesh','8790575680','7-Nov','18-Nov','28-Nov','','',''))
```

When i have multiple rows to insert my `INSERT INTO` query looks like this for `multiple rows`

```
INSERT INTO December_2015(S_No,Zone,State,City2,VM_Town,Distibutor_Code,Distributor_Name,Dealer_Code,Dealer_Name,Category,Address,Location,Contact,Mobile_No,Visit_1,Visit_2,Visit_3,Visit_4,Visit_5,Visit_6) VALUES(('1','South','Telanagana','Hyderabad','Y','1006704','Sai Santhoshi Enterprises','TG000999','Sree Laxmi Mobiles','A','F4,anthem Arcade,gujarathi Galli,koti ','Koti','Rajesh','8790575680','7-Nov','18-Nov','28-Nov','','',''),('2','South','Telanagana','Hyderabad','Y','1006704','Sai Santhoshi Enterprises','TG000997','National Marketing','C','Shop No:28,2nd Floor,anthem Arcade,Gujarati Galli,koti ','Koti','Ramesh','9989014926','7-Nov','18-Nov','28-Nov','','',''))
```

and thats why i have two brackets in my query but it returns error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an outside bracket. Just brackets around each record.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6);
```